# Overfitting in Tensorflow Object detection API

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection, tensorboard, object-detection-api

I am training tensorflow object detection API model on the custom dataset i.e. License plate dataset. **My goal is to deploy this model to the edge device using tensorflow lite so I can't use any RCNN family model**. Because, I can't convert any RCNN family object detection model to tensorflow lite model (this is the limitation from tensorflow object detection API). I am using [**ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco**](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md) model  to train the custom dataset. Following is the code snippet of my config file:

```
model {
  ssd {
    num_classes: 1
    box_coder {
      faster_rcnn_box_coder {
        y_scale: 10.0
        x_scale: 10.0
        height_scale: 5.0
        width_scale: 5.0
      }
    }
    matcher {
      argmax_matcher {
        matched_threshold: 0.5
        unmatched_threshold: 0.5
        ignore_thresholds: false
        negatives_lower_than_unmatched: true
        force_match_for_each_row: true
      }
    }
    similarity_calculator {
      iou_similarity {
      }
    }
    anchor_generator {
      ssd_anchor_generator {
        num_layers: 6
        min_scale: 0.2
        max_scale: 0.95
        aspect_ratios: 1.0
        aspect_ratios: 2.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.5
        aspect_ratios: 3.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.3333
      }
    }
    image_resizer {
      fixed_shape_resizer {
        height: 300
        width: 300
      }
    }
    box_predictor {
      convolutional_box_predictor {
        min_depth: 0
        max_depth: 0
        num_layers_before_predictor: 0
        use_dropout: false
        dropout_keep_probability: 0.8
        kernel_size: 1
        box_code_size: 4
        apply_sigmoid_to_scores: false
        conv_hyperparams {
          activation: RELU_6,
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.00004
            }
          }
          initializer {
            truncated_normal_initializer {
              stddev: 0.03
              mean: 0.0
            }
          }
          batch_norm {
            train: true,
            scale: true,
            center: true,
            decay: 0.9997,
            epsilon: 0.001,
          }
        }
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: 'ssd_mobilenet_v2'
      min_depth: 16
      depth_multiplier: 1.0
      conv_hyperparams {
        activation: RELU_6,
        regularizer {
          l2_regularizer {
            weight: 0.00004
          }
        }
        initializer {
          truncated_normal_initializer {
            stddev: 0.03
            mean: 0.0
          }
        }
        batch_norm {
          train: true,
          scale: true,
          center: true,
          decay: 0.9997,
          epsilon: 0.001,
        }
      }
    }
    loss {
      classification_loss {
        weighted_sigmoid {
        }
      }
      localization_loss {
        weighted_smooth_l1 {
        }
      }
      hard_example_miner {
        num_hard_examples: 3000
        iou_threshold: 0.99
        loss_type: CLASSIFICATION
        max_negatives_per_positive: 3
        min_negatives_per_image: 3
      }
      classification_weight: 1.0
      localization_weight: 1.0
    }
    normalize_loss_by_num_matches: true
    post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 1e-8
        iou_threshold: 0.6
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 100
      }
      score_converter: SIGMOID
    }
  }
}

train_config: {
  batch_size: 24
  optimizer {
    rms_prop_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        exponential_decay_learning_rate {
          initial_learning_rate: 0.004
          decay_steps: 800720
          decay_factor: 0.95
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
      decay: 0.9
      epsilon: 1.0
    }
  }
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "/home/sach/DL/Pycharm_Workspace/TF1.14/License_Plate_F-RCNN/dataset/experiments/training_SSD/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29/model.ckpt"
  fine_tune_checkpoint_type:  "detection"
  num_steps: 150000
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    ssd_random_crop {
    }
  }
}

train_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "/home/sach/DL/Pycharm_Workspace/TF1.14/License_Plate_F-RCNN/dataset/records/training.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "/home/sach/DL/Pycharm_Workspace/TF1.14/License_Plate_F-RCNN/dataset/records/classes.pbtxt"
}

eval_config: {
  num_examples: 488
  num_visualizations : 488
}

eval_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "/home/sach/DL/Pycharm_Workspace/TF1.14/License_Plate_F-RCNN/dataset/records/testing.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "/home/sach/DL/Pycharm_Workspace/TF1.14/License_Plate_F-RCNN/dataset/records/classes.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_readers: 1
}
```

**I have total 1932 images (train images: 1444 and val images: 448). I have trained the model for 150000 steps**. Following is the output from tensorboard:

**DetectionBoxes Precision mAP@0.5 IOU**: After 150K steps, the object detection model accuracy (mAP@0.5 IOU) is ~0.97 i.e. 97%. Which seems to be fine at the moment.

[image: DetectionBoxes_Precision_mAP]

**Training Loss:** After 150K steps, the training loss is ~1.3. This seems to be okay.

[image: Training Loss]

**Evaluation/Validation Loss**: After 150K steps, the evaluation/validation loss is ~3.90 which is pretty high. However, there is huge difference between training and evaluation loss. Is there any overfitting exist? How can I overcome this problem? In my point of view, training and evaluation loss should be close to each other.

[image: Eval Loss Loss]

- How can I reduce validation/evaluation loss?
- I am using the default config file so by default `use_dropout: false`. Should I change it to `use_dropout: true` in case overfitting exist?
- What should be the acceptable range of training and validation loss for object detection model?

Please share your views. Thanking you!

Comment: why is the num_classes is 1 ? is it the way it is supposed to be  ? or am i missing somthing ?

Comment: Hi, it should be 1 because of I am looking for only one class i.e "License Plate".

Comment: oh right.. as you mentioned, you can go ahead with using dropouts. Then as a first step, I would recommend you to add some augmentations. choose augmentations specifically considering the license plates. Step 2 would be adjusting your anchors. Have a look at this url to check how to optmize detection by generating anchors. https://github.com/joydeepmedhi/Anchor-Boxes-with-KMeans

Comment: Should I also enable learning rate decay of about 10% every 5000 steps? Because in the default config file learning rate decay is n't enabled. Bcoz of `decay_steps: 800720` it will work after only 800720 steps.

Comment: yes. cant keep it a crude way at 5000 steps. will be too often. try setting it around 20000 or even 30000. typically i would say atleast 2 epochs.

Comment: I looked at https://github.com/joydeepmedhi/Anchor-Boxes-with-KMeans but I can't find any "How can I specify anchor for SSD?" That's not clear. Could you please guide me? Thank you!

Comment: Just one question: What you mean by atleast 2 epochs? Can you please map this epochs field to config file? Setting `decay_steps : 20000` or `decay_steps: 30000` (this is clear).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209070/discussion-between-saurabh-chauhan-and-venkata-krishnan).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several reasons for overfitting problem In Neural networks, by looking at your config file, I would like to suggest a few things to try to avoid overfitting.

`use_dropout: true` so that it makes the Neurons less sensitive to minor changes in the weights.

Try increasing `iou_threshold` in `batch_non_max_suppression`.

Use `l1 regularizer` or combination of `l1 and l2 regularizer`.

Change the optimizer to `Nadam` or `Adam` Optimizers.

Include more `Augmentation` techniques.

You can also use `Early Stopping` to track your accuracy.

Alternatively, you can observe the `Tensorboard` visualization, take the weights before the step where the validation loss starts increasing.

I hope trying these steps will resolve the overfitting issue of your model.